# Predicting result of multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multivariate-analysis

I have a wood-burning lambda-controlled furnace that collects a number of variables during its operation once a minute, such as:

- exhaust oxygen content (lambda probe)
- exhaust temperature
- furnace temperature
- air inlet opening percentage (0-100%)
- exhaust fan speed
- mode of operation (off, ignition, full power, half power)

In addition, I measure how much heat energy goes into the house and **can hence compute the amount of energy that came from one cycle**. This is the value I would like to know right after the burning process is finished. Right now, I can only compute it in retrospect.

**The goal is to predict/compute, how much energy a given burning cycle has produced** so that I can estimate when and how much to put into the furnace for the next cycle.

A regular regression using the cumulative time spent in *full power* and *half power* mode during a cycle already gives a reasonable result. However, every cycle is slightly different and the other detailed variables collected should give sufficient insight to allow a more accurate prediction.

Physically, every point in time collected contributes a fraction of energy to the total. I do have the total energy in retrospect. This can be used for training the algorithm but I don't know the (hidden) relationship or weights of the individual variables that lead to this total.

**What algorithm would be suitable for predicting the result (amount of energy produced) of a given burning cycle using the data from these combined time series?**

Using Python would be great.